# Would it be possible to draw this stacked bar chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization

I have a data frame named `act_df` like this:
[Average sedentary hours, average lightly active hours, average fairly active hours, average very active hours per a person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHnwh.png)

```r
int_by_id<-group_by(daily_intensity_minutes,Id)
act_df <- summarise(int_by_id,avg_sd_hr=round(mean(SedentaryMinutes)/60),
  avg_light_actv_hr=round(mean(LightlyActiveMinutes)/60), 
  avg_fairly_actv_hr=round(mean(FairlyActiveMinutes)/60),
  avg_very_actv_hr=round(mean(VeryActiveMinutes)/60))
```

I manipulated data by using `group by` and `summarize` function to see average activity per person.

And I want draw bar chart in this way:
[image: Id on Y-axis and the each bar is filled with other columns like average sedentary hours, average lightly active hours]

Would it be possible to visualize this in R?

I am asking this because I don't know what to write down in the blank after fill while using ggplot2.( fill='___') Usually, in the blank, one of columns in it. However, for my case, all the columns except 'Id' are filling the bars.

Comment: Can you please post your example data frame in a *text* format rather than as an image? (You could use `dput()` or you could use a code block for your tabular data)

Comment: (Yes, with `ggplot`.  What have you tried so far?)

Comment: Thank you for quick respond but I don't what to write down after "fill=___" .

Comment: Typically you would reshape your data from wide to long (aka "tidy") so that "type of activity" would be encoded into a variable instead of as multiple variables. `library(tidyverse); act_df %>% pivot_longer(-Id) %>% ggplot(aes(value, Id, fill = name)) + geom_col()`

Answer (score 1):

Your data in it's current form is not ["tidy"](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html). When it is, the grammar of graphics in `ggplot2` make the task of data visualisation simpler.

First, you must [pivot your data from wide to long](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
act_df <- act_df %>%
    pivot_longer(!Id, names_to = "hour_type", values_to = "hours")
```

Then, you need to use the `geom_col()` in `ggplot2` to get the result you require:

```
act_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Id, y = hours, fill = hour_type)) +
    geom_col(position = "fill") +
    coord_flip()
```

I suspect the best move forward is to re-evaluate whether you need to summarise in the first place.

Comment: Since ggplot3 v3, most geoms can be specified with the x/y you want so that you don't need to call coord_flip. So I think `aes(x = hours, y = Id...` would work here.